# django: Nonelogout in admin urls

Tags: python, django, admin, url

After upgrading to Django 1.2 I have strange urls in my administration panel. They look like this:

```
http://example.com/admin/Nonelogout/
```

or

```
http://example.com/admin/Nonepassword_change/
```

What might have gone wrong during the migration and what I need to fix?

I have found in django source, that it is caused by root_path, but I have no idea, where I can set it properly or whether should I even do it.

Part of my urls.py for admin look like this:

```
(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
# (r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root),
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

Comment: Can you paste (or link to a dpaste of) your urls.py?

Comment: I have added part of urls.py for admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't found an answer for this, here is what I did... (and it is a hack, but it is the only thing that made it work).

In urls.py:

```
admin.site.root_path = ''
```

But I would be happy to see someone come out with a better solution.